# Aurebesh vs Aurebesh Droid fonts

Tags: star-wars

What is the difference between the Aurebesh and Aurebesh Droid fonts, and why doesn't the Droid version of the font have any way to type the special characters for 'ch'/'sh', etc like the ligature version does? Typing 'Sh' instead of 'sh' will enter the special character instead of just 's-h' using the ligature font.

See [dafont](https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=aurebesh&text=aurebesh&psize=s). It doesn't have the ligature version. Only the standard and Droid version, plus a few others.

With & without ligatures:

[image: aurebesh with & without ligatures]

Comment: Also, and I am saddened by this because I thought they were cool, it seems that the digraph replacement characters are not canon any more. They don't show up on the official [Ghost Crew ID Card (PDF)](http://a.dolimg.com/en-US/dxd/media/starwarsrebels/SWR_Ghost_Crew_ID_card.pdf), and Bodhi Rook's ID card in Rogue One showed what looked like Resh-Osk-Osk-Krill. (Maybe there was an Imperial spelling reform, but I doubt it.)

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is that Stephen Crane of West End Games more or less invented the canonical [Aurebesh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurebesh), which has a few variants in-universe, as character sets tend to do. There is no official Aurebesh font as far as I can tell, although there are a lot of fan versions, including some that do do ligatures, or account for ASCII characters not canonical to the Star Wars universe.

Aurebesh Droid is an unofficial alphabet designed by [Stormtrooper on Weekends](http://luc.devroye.org/fonts-101962.html), possibly based on the style sometimes called Droidobesh, as seen on Black Spire Outpost.

Comment: What's really interesting about Aurebesh is that it is not really original at all, but is heavily based on the Hebrew alphabet. Peth is a Hebrew "פ" flipped and rotated, Qek is a Hebrew "ק" flipped and missing its descender, and Dorn is a Hebrew "ד" with an extra cross-bar.

Comment: Given how much real-world scripts can vary (look at how wildly varying the typefaces are that we consider the same Latin alphabet!) it seems perfectly reasonable to headcanon the fonts as in-universe variants, and use whichever floats your X-Wing.

Comment: @IMSoP - but as we have seen - X-Wings don't float ;D

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm pretty sure senth is derived from sin/shin ש too.

Comment: @jastako I noticed that too, but just wanted to give a few examples. Most of the other letters have some relationship as well, and most of the others are obviously Greek and/or Arabic.

Answer (score 7):

The long answer:

"Aurebesh Droid" is based on a version of Aurebesh first seen at Disney parks as part of Galaxy's Edge called "[Droidobesh](https://aurekfonts.github.io/?script=Droidobesh)". Specifically, it is based on the Beta version of the font seen in the "Datapad" app: "Droidobesh Neue BETA".

"Droidobesh" was initially designed by [Sonny Nguyen](http://sonnytiennguyen.com/Walt-Disney-Imagineering). He also designed a few other variations for the parks, though not all of them have been identified.

The movement of designing new variants of Aurebesh began during pre-production on *Rogue One*; director Gareth Edwards wanted more than one font to be used throughout the galaxy. Among the fonts created for *Rogue One* were "[Domabesh](https://aurekfonts.github.io/?script=Domabesh)" (seen around Jedha), "[Dishabesh](https://twitter.com/AurekFonts/status/1277874005198827521)" (later seen on Enfys Nest's helmet in *Solo*), and "[Protobesh](https://aurekfonts.github.io/?script=Protobesh)" (the main language of the sacred Jedi texts in the *Rise of Skywalker*).

As for why the digraphs (double-letters) are no longer used officially, that probably began sometime during the production of *The Clone Wars* animated series, when they determined that it made spell-checking easier. According to Lucasfilm's "Holocron Keeper" Leeland Chee, the digraphs have been almost 100% retired since the Sequel Trilogy began, and none of their internal fonts use them anymore. However, they do occasionally show up now and again in decorative capacities.

TL;DR - "Aurebesh Droid" doesn't use digraphs, because Lucasfilm no longer uses digraphs.

ps - Aurebesh was not based upon Hebrew, [but a chopped up letraset copy of Eurostile Bold Extended](https://twitter.com/daveaddey/status/957662636258164736?s=20). That said, most of the written text in the Original Trilogy consists of the letraset Hebrew fonts "Hebrew Microgramma," "Armon," and "Rahel." Just not the Aurebesh specifically.

pps - Might I recommend "[Aurebesh AF](https://aurekfonts.github.io/?font=AurebeshAF) Canon" as the most accurate and complete Aurebesh font available. It also comes in "Aurebesh AF Legends," if you prefer to keep using the digraphs, and also has "Tech" styles that let you use an alternate numeral system.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I couldn't find anything canonical on Droidobesh, and I was starting to think it was a fanwork.

Comment: Thank you for the font history, and your own fonts there. I've been using some old fan-made Aurebesh fonts that had the digraphs for a while (I forget who made them), but they haven't been playing nice with modern OSs.